# Sound with certain volume in Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, audio, cocos2d-iphone, volume

I am playing a sound with SimpleAudioEngine.h in Cocos2d. It plays the sound just like it would in iTunes. But can I set the volume? Help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im pretty sure SimpleAudioEngine has two properties for that: backgroundMusicVolume
and effectsVolume

```
audioengine.effectsVolume = 0.5; //Half volume
audioengine.backgroundMusicVolume = 0.5; //Half volume
```

Basically the range is from 0.0 to 1.0 and it is a float.
Hope that does it for you.

Comment: I figured it out, and it should go like so:                                   [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setBackgroundMusicVolume:0.2f];

Comment: Mine works too if you do this: SimpleAudioEngine *audioengine = [SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]; and then: audioengine.effectsVolume = 0.5; Just to let you know...